# Every nonempty, compact convex set $M$ in a locally convex space has fixed point property

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, nonlinear-analysis

I need to prove that "Every nonempty, compact convex set $M$  in a locally convex space has fixed point property".

In the book the reference has been given to "Eisenack & Frenske, 1944, page 44". I am unable to find the book. Also how do I proceed? I can try proving if the problem can be divided into smaller parts as well.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Would you please write full address of the book?

Answer (score 1):

The result you are looking for is called [Tychonoff's fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_theorems_in_infinite-dimensional_spaces), a generalization of Schauder's theorem for locally convex spaces.

For a proof of this result you can look at *Eberhard Zeidler "Nonlinear functional analysis and its applications, Vol.
1: Fixed-point theorems", Springer, New York, 1986*. But knowing the name you might just be able to google and find other references online.